# How to create handler in objective-c

Tags: android, objective-c, multithreading, handler, sleep

I have to create an app for iDevice from another app what i created for android. I need to show a dialog for only two seconds. In android i uses this code:

```
public class ThreadW extends Thread{
    private Handler handler;
    public ThreadW(Handler handler){
       this.handler=handler;
    }
    public void run(){
        notifyM("start");
        Thread.sleep(2500);
        notifyM("stop");
    }
    private void notifyM(String message){
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("Dialog", message);
        msg.setData(b);
        handler.sendMessage(msg); 
    }
}
```

And handler:

```
public class HandlerWelcome extends Handler {
    private DialogWelcome w;
    private Context c ;
    public HandlerWelcome(Context c){
        this.c=c;
    }
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        if(bundle.getString("Dialog").equals("start")){
            w = new DialogWelcome(c);
            w.show();
        }else if(bundle.getString("Dialog").equals("stop"))
            w.cancel();
    }
}
```

And i use all in this way:

```
ThreadW tw = new Thread(new HandlerWelcome(c));
tw.start();
```

How can i do the same in objective c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) (GCD):

```
// Call this method on the main thread
- (void)showWelcomeMessage
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" 
                                                    message:@"Have a nice day!" 
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC*2.0);
    dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });

    [alert release];
}
```

However, you should create a custom alert dialog since iOS users won't be expecting a standard alert dialog to automatically disappear.

Comment: This is what i need! Thanks you very much!! :) another question, in this dispatch_after, can i put other method like call another view?

Comment: This code will leak, you need to release alert, or make alert an autorelease object. You shouldn't do any UI related stuff unless you are in the main thread. As such, you should replace [alert dismissWith...] with something like;  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateDone:) withObject:alert waitUntilDone:NO]; where updateDone then does : [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES]; [alert release];

Comment: @jyavenard Under ARC it won't leak. If you're not using ARC, you should indeed call `[alert autorelease]`. Also, calling any of the `dispatch_XXX` functions onto the main queue means it will execute on the main thread, so it's safe to do UI updates there.

Comment: @JackTurky: The block will execute on the main thread so any methods you call from there will also execute on the main thread.  (Short answer: yes.)

Comment: :P i don't understand the precedents comment you've done :) but i need only that yes :P thanks!!

Comment: UIAlertView doesn't have to show buttons, simply make otherButtonTitles:nil

Comment: @jyavenard: Good point, I made that edit.  I don't like how UIAlertView still leaves room for buttons that aren't there--that's just nitpicking though.

Comment: I altered the code not to assume that ARC is enabled since upon further reflection, it doesn't seem an appropriate assumption to make, particularly for such a small snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `NSTimer` class. It would allow you to set up a delayed execution of a specific target and selector (an object and a method on that object). A method like `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` could be what you need.

Have a look at the [class documentation on the Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for full details.